# Download video file from one server to another

Tags: php

Is there any way to download a video file from any server to my lamp (linux-apache-mysql-php) server using php?

I googled so much but couldn't find yet.

Comment: We need more information. Does that include Youtube videos?

Comment: this will also be ok.. but if i want if it is possible that we download video file from any url to our server?

Comment: What have you tried? Assuming you have a direct URL to the file in question, [`fopen()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) is a good place in the documentation to start.

Comment: can we find out the video availablity from any url, if yes then script should download it automatically otherwise an alert message should be given to acknowledge about copying file issue.

Comment: guys.. any suggestions / help??

Comment: Ok.. If i'd say i just need to copy youtube videos to my server.. kindly help!!

Comment: So you want, given any url like youtube.com/whatever, to check if there's any video embedded to that page and if so, download that video as a file?

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day I would use fopen() or I would use wget to download the file. Sometimes just leaving it to wget works really well because it requres you to program a lot less and has a lot of features built right into it.